# pasting a time format cell as number.

Tags: excel

'
I'm working on excel for my project.

one of my cell is formatted as custom of type "h" for example 6.

I copy that cell and i paste special value onto another cell, it returns me 0.25

my ideal result is just 6 as a number.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, dates are stored from an original date: `01/01/1900 00:00:00` and converted to a kind of timestamp in which every day is 1 unit.

```
1 -> 01/01/1900 00:00:00
2 -> 02/01/1900 00:00:00
3 -> 03/01/1900 00:00:00
```

and so on.

Hence, even if Excel is displaying `6` in a cell formated as a date (`h` is a part of a date), the inner value is `0,25`, corresponding to `00/01/1900 00:06:00` (ok `00` doesn't exist, I only intend to show this as an example).

I can't see any easy way to Copy-Paste Values to another cell without getting this behavior.

I suggest two workarounds:

1. Change the format of the targeted cell to a date (or `h`)
2. Use a formula in the target cell, something like `=HOURS(A1)`